# Need Help Playing Voice Memo

Tags: recording, voice, playback, file-conversion, fix

I recorded a voice memo that 13+ hours long. It will only play the first 4 seconds. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You might have more success reaching out to tech support for your phone.

Answer (score 1):

If your recording is on a dedicated portable voice recorder and it does not play back, then that may be a problem with the recording, such as a corrupted SD card. If this recording is on a mobile phone, the best thing to do is to export the file to a computer. Use the sharing options on your device, or some recording apps offer the option to act as a web server you can simply reach from a different device on the same wireless network, and download the file as if you were downloading any other file from the web. If the file still does not play on other devices, you may have a corrupted recording.